# Buying a new router because my ISP is blocking port forward

Tags: networking, router, port-forwarding, isp

So I believe my ISP is blocking certain port. My question is simple, if I purchase a new router, is it going to fix the issue? Thanks

Comment: Are you trying a certain port?  If so what is it? You could also try placing the device in the DMZ zone and see if the ports are open to determine if your Isp is blocking them.

Comment: If the ISP is blocking a new router won't help and is a waste of your money.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No If they are blocking it's not at router level

Comment: not sure why im getting downvote but thanks! Will mark as answer later

Comment: I would recommend checking whether port is actually blocked many times it's wrong port forwarding start a new question and post info like router model screenshots of your settings